# Issues with having a plane on xy, axis

Tags: 3d

I am trying to create a drawing for the riemann sphere, and I want an xy plane that is perpendicular to the z-axis. When I use the scope enviornment, I can get to a correct rotation, but it also rotates everything in my drawing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\fontsize{8}{30}\selectfont]

%% plane with 
\def\R{1.8} % for phi angle
\begin{scope}  [x={(0.5cm,-0.1cm)}, y={(0.25cm,0.435cm)}, z={(0cm,0.8cm)}, scale=2.5]
\begin{scope} [every path/.style={thin}]
\begin{scope} [canvas is xy plane at z=0]
 %the plane
 \draw [fill=green!10] (-2.2,-2)--(-2,2)--(2,2)--(2.2,-2)--cycle; 
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
% Axes
\draw[->] (0,-1)--(1.4,-1) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,1) node[above] {$N = (0,0,1)$};
\draw[->] (0,-1)--(-1,-2) node[below left] {$x$};
% Vector and label node
\draw[->] (0,1)--(.3,-2);
\draw (1, -2) node {$P = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0)$};
\draw (.2,0) node {${G}$};
\draw (0,0) circle(1);
\draw [fill = blue,opacity = .2] plot[domain=pi:2*pi] ({cos(\x r)},{.4*sin(\x r)});
\draw[dashed] plot[domain=0:pi] ({cos(\x r)},{.3*sin(\x r)});
\draw [fill = blue, opacity = .2] plot[domain=0:pi] ({cos(\x r)},{.3*sin(\x r)});
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please can you make your code into a compilable example? That way, people don't have to guess and it's easier to help.